# Synchronous Multi Threaded Merge Sort

Tags: c, multithreading, synchronization, mutex, mergesort

I am trying to sort n numbers of an array my m threads. 
So given an array of 49 10 34 9 32 37 48 37, 
For the first part of the merge sort, I slice(n/m) into parts and have each thread sort their part.
n=8;
m=4
So, now I get this.

Thread0 Thread1 Thread2 Thread3
10 49  ....  9 34......   32 37.....   37 48

Now, thread 0 will wait for a signal from thread 1 and thread 2 will wait for a signal form thread3 in order to merge on the first level. In the next lelvel, thread 0 will be merged with thread 3 to get the final result.

```
void *start(void *arg){
    struct tsk *tsk = arg;
    int low;
    int high;
    int levels = log2 (m); // gets the # of levels 

    // get low and high of each thread
    low = tsk->low;
    high=tsk->high;
    //printf("%d", low);

    // mid-point
    int mid = low + (high - low) / 2;
    if (low < high){
        merge_sort(low,mid);
        merge_sort(mid+1,high);
        merge(low, mid, high);

    }
    int i;

    /* Local Synchronization
    for(i = 0; i < levels; i++){
        if(id % 2 == 0){
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
            pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex); 


        }
    }*/
}
```

I am stuck as to how to write the conditions to merge parts sorted by threads at each level.

Comment: Here's something I found with a web search that looks pretty good: https://malithjayaweera.com/2019/02/parallel-merge-sort/

Comment: Link to [C++ example](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/148025/) using Windows native threads. It uses separate functions for each thread to keep the threads simple.